# audio processing for audio files quick listening

Tags: audio

I need to speed the listening task. I want to listen only 1 second every three seconds.
Could you give me some advice?
Many thanks!
Best regards, Sergio

Comment: so you want *time-compression* where you speed it up by a factor of 3 without changing pitch?

Comment: No, Robert. I do not want to speed the play. The play of the audio has to be as the original mp3 file. Vice versa I want to listen 1 second every 4 so I can have only a rough idea of the audio content. I'm thinking to a script that processes the mp3 file sampling just slices with a configurable time window length. Thank you for your help

Comment: This can be easily done in numerical computing packages such as Octave, SciPy, Matlab, etc. Load the mp3 into an array; slice the array to your liking; save the sliced array as a new mp3.

Comment: Yes, MBaz. I'm now reconsidering Octave, which I discarded thinking it was applicable but with too high difficulty. Thank you for mentoring me.

Comment: Abstract: I need to make a script that slices an MP3 file, extracts those slices and recomposes them in a shorter MP3 file.
Have you already carried out a similar task? Is a tutorial available? If so, where can I find it?
Please let me know if my question is unclear to you.